# How to use database to generate multiple folder content page?

Tags: php, web, sql

Scenario :I am trying to build a Mobile Entertainment Portal. It will enable users to download Music & Movies to their Cell Phones...

Problem Exp : Suppose I upload 100 folders of Songs, each folder is for one Album. I want a way to generate a page with all the folders name (Album Name) in it. If user click on the page, they should be taken to a page where they get list of all songs in the album. Clicking on any song name will let them download it. Can it be done anyway or will I have to manually design each of the 3 pages for each album. If I do that, its time consuming and also will be difficult to change anything like footer, header...

Comment: This is possible using just PHP. Anyway this is a programmin question and doesn't belong here (but stackoverflow).

Comment: I think you need to buy some books on programming.

Comment: I nidda complete this project in one week. Short of time..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this is a weighted question.  But I will try to answer some of your questions to get you started.

You can scan for directories using `scandir()` in PHP.

```
$path = '/path/to/music';
$dir  = scandir($path);
if (is_array($dir)) {
    foreach ($dir as $directory) {
        if (is_dir("{$path}/{$directory}")) {
            // validate that it's among the directories you want
        }
    }
}
```

So, now that you know how to do that, perhaps instead of trying to create a separate page for each album folder you could use one script and based on the `GET` vars, display the appropriate content. e.g.

```
domain.com/index.php?album=Album+Name
```

Now let's see how that might work with the above example:

```
// assume your album folder names use underscores
$album = (isset($_GET['album'])) 
    ? str_replace('+', '_', $_GET['album'])
    : null;
$path  = '/path/to/music';
$dir   = scandir($path);
if (is_array($dir)) {
    foreach ($dir as $directory) {
        if (is_dir("{$path}/{$directory}") && $album == $directory) {
            // now, scan for files
        }
    }
}
```

Then to get the files, when you're looping through the directories, instead of checking if it *is* a directory, check that it's *not* a directory and that will give you your files.  (e.g. `if (!is_dir(...`)